# Flask server cannot start due to the lack of libgcc

Tags: python, linux, gcc, flask, raspberry-pi

I have created flask server for my app, which I want to run on raspbian, on raspberry pi. When trying to start with flask run I've got info that `libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work Aborted.`
It looks like server has been started, but just after that it has been immediately stopped.

Tryed already to install libgcc-8-dev via `apt-get install` but no success.

Also found that library can be downloaded from here: https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=libgcc_s.so.1&searchmode=searchfiles&case=insensitive&version=stable&arch=i386

but I have no idea which one should I pick and how to install it properly (where to place it and how to link it)?

[image]

Comment: perhaps a 32bit vs 64bit issue: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/libgcc_s-so-1-must-be-installed-for-pthread_cancel-to-work-4175474124/

Comment: I have just checked and my OS is 32 bit, co I assume that libgcc is for 64 bit? Tryed ```yum provides */libgcc_s.so.1``` but no matches found. Tryed also ```yum install libgcc.i686``` but there are no enabled repos

Comment: Is this the latest raspian? What happens if you try your app on fresh install without adding libgcc-8-dev? And is your app attempting to use threads?

Comment: Just installed fresh raspbian. Only installed necessary packages, but problem is the same. Feel free to check my code here: https://gitlab.com/gawron103/peephole/tree/server_branch

Answer (score 0):

If you using something like openCV, then try to find out its headless version.

For me that problem was coming due to openCV. Then I install its **headless** version and it works fine.

**Example**:- sudo pip3 install opencv-python-headless